# how can I guarantee that a repeat visitor won't cause the server to repeat an action?

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

I want the server to make a change to a database when a first time user visits.  I don't want it to be easy for a user to pretend to be a first time visitor again (such as deleting his cookie). Does anyone have ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Difficult to do reliably. Often a combination of IP address and user-agent string is used, but that causes problems for users behind a NAT. Plus if they really wanted to, they could modify their user-agent string too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short of making them login there is not much. If you log ip address you will not be able to distinguish behind NAT.

Answer (score 0):

Track a user's HTTP header data.  Note that this will not be accurate if users at the same IP are using computers with identical configurations.